# JavaScript Function Execution Order

Tags: javascript

Say you have the following three functions and variable

```
var someList = [];

makeObject() {

 // loops through someList here to create an object
 // then calls sendObject function

sendObject()

}

sendObject() {
 // sends object to database using HTTP call
}

resetList() {
 // resets the list to be empty
 // e.g. someList = []
}
```

Then you call them like so

```
makeObject()
resetList()
```

Is there any possiblity or any situation that the list will be reset before the makeObject function has a chance to loop through it?

Comment: What is the loop? A `for` statement?

Comment: Yes it is a for statement.

Comment: Then no, the `for` loop will *always* finish before `sendObject()` runs.

Comment: Please don't post an extremely vague bit of code and then slip in extra bits of detail. It's just not a good way to ask people for help. What you're asking is if the `for` loop will always finish before the list is reset, and the answer is "yes". If you have a specific situation that you're wondering about, then please be specific from the start.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of things you can do in JavaScript which are asynchronous and non-blocking (`XMLHttpRequest` and `setTimeout` are classic examples). If you use any of those inside `makeObject` then `resetList` will run before the asynchronous parts get called.

Comment: How about appending data to a FromData object?

Comment: Nothing async about that

Comment: Last question i'll bother you with; what if I was passing the following into makeObject; var deferred = $q.defer(). e.g. makeObject(deferred) ?

Comment: I have no idea what `$q` is.

Answer (score 2):

resetList() will be called directly after the HTTP call is made. Unless you do other async work before the HTTP call, the order will always be:

- makeObject()
- loop inside makeObject()
- sendObject() is called from inside makeObject()
- sendObject() does the HTTP call
- resetList() gets triggered right after the HTTP call since that HTTP call is async.
- The HTTP returns and any handlers attached to it are triggered.

But make sure that you don't do any other async work, else this will not apply.

Comment: This is a far better answer. Shouldn't be downvoted by... (well, he knows who he is).

Comment: What if I was passing the following into makeObject; var deferred = $q.defer(). e.g. makeObject(deferred) ($q is a promise library in Angular)

Comment: That depends on what you do with that deferred and in which spot the call to `sendObject()` is amde, so you'll have to show more code to say anything sensible about that situation. But since you ask you probably want to chain another `.then(fn)` to that deferred? In that case you'll need to make sure the call to `sendObject()` is inside the callback for that `.then()` so that it can't get triggered before the deferred resolves.